# Django 1.10 upload file. form is not valid

Tags: python, django, forms

I try upload file from Form in Django.
I use Django 1.10.

my form

```
<form   id='form_'  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input id="fileupload"  data-url="{% url 'analyzer:upload_files' %}"
   data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'
  type="file" name="file" multiple>
  <p>Drag your file(s) here or click in this area.</p>
</form>
```

my views

```
def upload_files(request):

    print(request.FILES, request.user.username)
    if request.POST:
        print('ok')
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if  form.is_valid():
            print('YEEEES')

            return JsonResponse({'data':'ok', 'is_valid': True})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'data':'Bad', 'is_valid': False})
```

my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import File

class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = File
        fields = ('file_upload','user',)
```

my model

```
from django.db import models

def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return ('user_%s/%s' %(instance.user.id, filename))

class File(models.Model):

    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    id_user = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.TextField()
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    file_upload = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')
    file_size = models.IntegerField()
    file_name = models.TextField()
```

I do not know what I'm doing wrong. My form is not valid. 
Please, help me!
P.S. 
Still, I'm trying to save the file for each user separately, but examples from the Internet do not help

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Rather than just showing that the form is not valid, you should at least show the content of `form.errors` so that we and the user know what is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than just showing that the form is not valid, you should at least show the content of `form.errors` so that we and the user know what is causing it.

However, from your code it is clear that the form requires a value for the `user` field, but your HTML is not supplying it.

Comment: i paste in my code - print (forms.errors) and print this:<ul class="errorlist"><li>file_upload<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is req
uired.</li></ul></li></ul>

Comment: i delete field 'user' in 
class Meta:

        model = File
        fields = ('file_upload',)

Comment: Is it necessary to make migration for this model?

Comment: No, why would it have anything to do with migrations? The error now tells you that it is expecting a `file_upload` field, but you are only providing a field with the name `file`.

Comment: I understand! Thanks you!